# Best way to retrieve data attributes in Python?

Tags: python, coding-style

I have a question that is puzzling me recently about which is the best way to retrieve attributes from outside.

Let say I have a class:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, whatever):
        self.whatever = whatever

x = Thing('foo')
```

Now I know that if I want to retrieve `whatever` attribute I can do this:

```
x.whatever
```

I have the habit (probably because I come from other oo languages) to define methods to retrieve class attributes as needed and use them insted of retrieve them directly, like:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, whatever):
        self.whatever = whatever

    def getWhatever(self):
        return self.whatever
```

In my little experience I've found that using this approach make things easier to mantain in the long term because if I edit the structure of data attributes I have to edit only the specific method.

But since I am not really a python veteran I'd love to know if I am doin' it right or if some other approaches are better and more pythonic. Thoughts?

Comment: Here, `whatever` is not a *class* attribute, but an instance one. Class attributes pertains to the class, and have the same value for every instances.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Defining explicit getters and setters is a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/python-property-versus-getters-and-setters/6618184#6618184) in Python. Instead, use [properties](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Thing(object): # New-style class
    def __init__(self, whatever):
        self._whatever = whatever

    @property
    def whatever(self):
        return self._whatever # Insert complicated calculation here
```

So instead of pre-planning by using get methods, just introduce a property when you actually need advanced behavior, and [not any earlier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it).

Answer (score 8):

@phihag has the right idea, and mentions in their answer, but to be more explicit about it:  The first step is simply to use the attribute directly:

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, whatever):
        self.whatever = whatever


t = Thing(12)
assert t.whatever == 12
```

Later, if you find you need to make the whatever attribute more sophisticated, you can turn it into a property:

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, whatever):
        self._whatever = whatever

    @property
    def whatever(self):
        return something_complicated(self._whatever)


t = Thing(12)
assert t.whatever == 12
```

This way, the calling code doesn't change, and you have a nice clean API to your object.

Answer (score 0):

check python property() http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property