# What is a good style around the use of getters/setters , properties while designing python classes

Tags: python, mongodb, orm, pymongo

I came across this python code base where there is a custom ORM code that maps to MongoDb. I was asked to write new Entities following the existing pattern of code. I have only been writing python code for a week now. But, i find this mix of getter style method name marked as property etc confusing. I know I am not giving a lot of context here. But, I want to discuss how this api looks from a good python programming api pov.

Its python 2.7.

```
class Entity(object):
    def save(self): 
    ...

class Person(Entity):
  ...
  @property
  def get_config(self):
    return getattr(self, 'config', None)

  def set_config(self, config):
    self.set('config', config)
  ...
```

Comment: Please phrase this as a question.  I'm pretty sure I can help if you do.

Comment: I tried to make it into a question. @BlackVegetable

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look that good.  There is no reason to use getters/setters in Python just to get and set static values.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852279/what-is-the-benefit-to-using-a-get-function-for-a-python-class).  You should only use them if you actually need to programmatically compute the attribute value on every access.

Also, instead of using `getattr` to return None if the attribute is undefined, you should just initialize it to None.  Then you can later read its value unconditionally.

So:

```
class Person(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize config to None
        self.config = None
```

Later, if other code needs to read the `config` attribute of a Person instance called somePerson, just do:

```
somePerson.config
```

If you need to set it, just do:

```
somePerson.config = newConfig
```

Comment: Agreed; if the pattern *does* demand computation on read/write it should make complete use of the getter/setter **decorator** pattern which uses a `@config.setter` decorator invocation as well as a getter.