# How to call a function within a class parameter

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I need some help with generating an instance of an object.

Lets say I have an object being created from NewPerson but I do not put a name
within the parameter like so:

```
dave = NewPerson()
```

I want to generate a random name using my generate_name function. Here is my current code, but I'm getting the error: NameError: name 'generate_name' is not defined

```
class NewPerson(object):
    def __init__(self, name = generate_name()):
        self.name = name
        self.age = 0

    def set_name(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return (self.name)

    def generate_name(self):
        self.name = Generator.get_full_name()
```

Comment: Forget about accessors in Python, just use `myclass.instance_variable`. If you need to, you can add accessors later if you truly need them by a change to the class definition, not all places that reference it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852279/what-is-the-benefit-to-using-a-get-function-for-a-python-class for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

(1) You need to indent after you declare the class - in this case all of your member function definitions

(2) Because of the indent problem, it's not clear if you want 'generate_name' to be a member function of the NewPerson class or if you want it to be a stand-alone function.
If you don't want it to be inside the class, then simply move its definition to *before* the definition of NewPerson, and everything should work fine:

```
def generate_name():
   [code here]

class NewPerson(object):
   [code here]
```

On the other hand, if you DO want generate_name to be a member function of NewPerson, then you can't do what you're trying, but a simple fix is something like the following (pay attention to the indenting):

```
def NewPerson(object):
   def __init__(self, name = None):
      if name == None:
         self.name = self.generate_name()
      else:
         self.name = name
   def generate_name(self):
      [code here]
```

The take-away message is that you need to use indenting to tell Python which pieces of code go with which other pieces. These are called *code block* and in other languages they might be handled with operators like { }, but in Python, having your indentation correct is very important since this marks your code blocks!

Answer (score 2):

the `import random` and `generate_name` function are because i dont know what your `Generate` class does

```
import random #just for a quick generate random name thing
class NewPerson(object):
    def __init__(self, name = fart_knock()):
        #this entire if/else block is equivilant to "self.name = name or self.generate_name()", thanks troolee
        if name == None:
            self.name = self.generate_name()
        else:
            self.name = name
        self.age = 0

    def generate_name(self):
        #because i have no idea how your Generator class works
        return str(random.randrange(9999))
```

yours isnt working properly, because you are trying to assign a function inside of the class into the **init** method. it doesnt know what it is before you create it. ( even if it did, it would do it once and every single random name would be the exact same)

also when calling a method inside of a class, inside of the class you need to refer to it as `self.generate_name()` instead of just `generate_name()`

Comment: `self.name = name or Generator.get_full_name()`

Comment: heh. thats pretty cool, i never thought of that. just looking at it (and before your edit) i thought you were crazy.... still not sure how it works, because on the surface it looks like `name or Generator.get_full_name()` should return a boolean ( i guess because i mostly use `or` in statements like `if a or b:`, (assuming `Generator.get_full_name()` returns a string of course

Comment: Operator `or` will return first non-false value. Also `or` is lazy, it means python will never call `Generator.get_full_name()` if name will be non-calse (None, empty string, 0, False, {}, (), [], etc).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,  to call functions on the instance, you need to preface them with `self`:

```
self.generate_name()
```

Secondly, if you put the `generate_name` call in the function header, it will be called *when the function is defined* and not again -- so you'll have one "random" default name.

Thirdly, if you really want that behavior, you have to define `generate_name` first, and leave `self` off (both when you call it and when you define it):

```
class NewPerson(object):

    def generate_name():
        blahblah

    def __init__(self, name=generate_name()):
        blahblah
```

This makes `generate_name` useless once the class is finished being constructed, unless you add something like:

```
    generate_name = staticmethod(generate_name)
```

towards the bottom of the class.