# Simpler way to do python operator overloading?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I am working on a graph library in Python and I am defining my vetex this way:

```
class Vertex:
def __init__(self,key,value):
    self._key = key
    self._value = value

@property
def key(self):
    return self._key

@key.setter
def key(self,newKey):
    self._key = newKey

@property
def value(self):
    return self._value

@value.setter
def value(self,newValue):
    self.value = newValue

def _testConsistency(self,other):
    if type(self) != type(other):
        raise Exception("Need two vertexes here!")

def __lt__(self,other):
    _testConsistency(other)
    if self.index <= other.index:
        return True
    return False
......
```

Do I really have to define __lt__,__eq__,__ne__....all by my self? It is so verbose. Is there simpler way I can get around this?
Cheers.
Please dont use __cmp__ since it will be away in python 3.

Comment: Why the properties? Why not just use regular attributes?

Comment: Umm @delnan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/python-property-versus-getters-and-setters this thread may help you

Comment: I know perfectly well how `property` works and why it's good. But it's still at least six lines more than just using an attribute (`self.key = ...` in `__init__`).

Comment: I think that delnan's point is that you can define `key` and `value` as regular attributes (no need for the `_`) and then you don't need the properties.  If you ever decide you *need* a property, then you can adjust the code and it will still be backward compatable.

Comment: +1 to delnan and mgilson's points, it's very bad form to define getters and setters, even with the property decorator, until you actually need them.

Comment: Oh good point, I used to program in java and I am more comfortable with setters and getters. Thanks, I will see which way is better by using them both and experiment. Thanks a lot for point out.

Comment: My question is, under what situation, a setter and getter is necessary for you in python?

Comment: @dorafmon Never, unless you're stuck with maintaining compatibility with a horrible API that does it. Properties are what you generally use when you'd use getters/setters in other languages. But if they do nothing (except, of course, delegating to an attribute), you don't need them. Only use them when you have additional logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[functools.total_ordering](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) can help you out here.  It's meant to be a class decorator.  You define one of `__lt__()`, `__le__()`, `__gt__()`, or `__ge__()` **AND** `__eq__` and it fills in the rest.

As a side note:

Instead of writing this

```
if self.index <= other.index:
    return True
return False
```

write this:

```
return self.index <= other.index
```

It's cleaner that way. :-)

Comment: Do I have to import anything to use this? I got error using @total_ordering. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`functools.total_ordering`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering), you only need to define one of the equality operators and one of the ordering operators. In Python < 3.2, you're out of luck, *something* has to define these operators as individual methods. Though you may be able to save some code by writing a simpler version of `total_ordering` yourself, if you need it in several places.