# @def vs @property, @foo.setter

Tags: python, properties

I decided to give learning python a go today, going in the traditional "try random things until something works" way.

I started reading about classes, and then properties, and I tried to create some on my own. Most examples, and even examples from questions on this site, define properties like this:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    # etc. taken from the python tutorial
```

When I start typing "@pro" in my text editor and hit tab, it completes to this:

```
# ... Class stuff ...
@def foo():
    doc = "The foo property."
    def fget(self):
        return self._foo
    def fset(self, value):
    self._foo = value
foo = property(**foo())
```

Do these do the same thing, if they do, which one should I use (i.e. which is considered better practice)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/python-property-versus-getters-and-setters)

Comment: `@def foo()` is invalid syntax

Comment: Your editor is using outdated autocompletions (pre -`@decorator`s) - it's completing `property` to `def foo() ...`, leaving the literal `@`.

Comment: @msvalkon Not at all, IMO.

Comment: @def appears to be broken behavior in sublime texts (And maybe others?) autocomplete. That said its a shame. It'd be a rather pleasing syntactical construction if it worked.

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned, `@def foo():` is invalid syntax and should be `def foo():`. With that one caveat, the two code samples you posted do pretty much the same thing. The `@` operator takes a function-that-works-on-functions and applies it to the next defined function. In other words:

```
@property
def the_answer():
    return 42
```

is exactly the same as:

```
def the_answer():
    return 42
the_answer = property(the_answer)
```

But the `@property` way of writing this is easier to write, read, and understand, which is why it's considered better practice.

Comment: A function-that-works-on-functions is usually called a "decorator", by the way. If you want to learn more about them, that's the term you should Google, not "function-that-works-on-functions". :-)

Comment: By the way, if you want to learn more about decorators, this answer to a question from 2009 is a fantastic tutorial on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python/1594484#1594484