# Flask logging to file - working locally but not on server

Tags: python, logging, flask, server

I am trying to diagnose some mysterious Internal Server Errors, so I added logging to the flask app. After digging through many explanations, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23173763/8230949) which I am using below, along with the suggestion to put everything inside a `@app.before_first_request` decorator.

Locally this works as expected and `werkzeuglog.log` contains exactly what is printed to the screen.

**But** on the server:

1. The log file is created.
2. Nothing is written to it.
3. No errors are thrown, at least not to the user

> ```
> @app.before_first_request
> def initialize():
>     logger = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
>     logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>     handler = logging.FileHandler('werkzeuglog.log')
>     logger.addHandler(handler)
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     #run app
>     app.run(
>         host="0.0.0.0",
>         port=int("80"),
>         debug=False
>     )
> ```

Am I doing something wrong or is this some server issue that is beyond my scope? Gentle answers appreciated!

**EDIT**:
Some context: An internal server error is caused when the user uploads a file and I am trying to figure out what's going wrong using the log.
I don't think it can be an issue with permissions since the script definitely creates the file. I checked that the disk is not full.

**EDIT 2**
I reran the run.fcgi file which starts the WSGI Server. Now the manual entries to the log file via `logger.info('blah blah')` show up but not the others i.e. `GET` `POST` etc.

I don't have access to `/var/log/nginx`. It's a student-volunteer run server so I would like to give them as much info as I can. But this is all I have so far.

Comment: Say details about the server. Are you sure your script has permission writing a new file in the server?

Comment: Script belongs to the user and does create the file successfully. I changed the log file permissions to -rw-rw-rw- to no effect.

Comment: Maybe the logs are redirected to the server logs, what server are you using ? Apache, nginx ?

Comment: I know is that it is wrapped in WSGI and all I can do at my end is edit the run.fcgi file.

Comment: Try to manually write something (at least at the debug level!) on every request, perhaps you're only logging at an info level which is ignored?

`logger.debug('This is a debug statement')` or
`logger.warning('This is a warning')`

Comment: Could you check the server logs or ask the guy-who-can? When you say it works locally, is it with the flask development server  ?

Comment: Yes locally means with the flask development server. Again manually writing to the logger works locally but not on the server.

Comment: could you check some files on the server ? don't know if the server is Apache or nginx, but look at the default paths, like `/var/log/apache2/` or `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, maybe the server configuration customize that. Look at this [doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/logging/#default-configuration)

Comment: Correction: manual entries show up (see edit in post). Honestly the flask logging docs are too much for me, so I would appreciate an explicit suggestion.