# Error with class method getter - Python

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm having a little bit of trouble with my method getter for getting the phone number. This is my code:

```
# Personal info class
class PersonalInfo:
    def set_names(self, name):
        self.__names = name

    def set_addresses(self, add):
        self.__addresses = add

    def set_ages(self, age):
        self.__ages = age

    def set_numbers(self, number):
        self.__numbers = number

    # Accessor methods    
    def get_names(self):
        return self.__names

    def get_addresses(self):
        return self.__addresses

    def get_ages(self):
        return self.__ages

    def get_numbers(self):
        return self.__numbers

def main():
    # references PersonalInfo object
    info = PersonalInfo()

    # stores values in the object
    info.set_names("Will")
    info.set_addresses("26 Explorer Blvd, Punta Gorda, FL")
    info.set_ages("21")
    info.set_numbers("941-245-0255")

    # displays values stored in object's fields
    print "Name:", info.get_names()
    print "Address:", info.get_addresses()
    print "Age:", info.get_ages()
    print "Phone number:", info.get_numbers
    print

    # stores new values
    info.set_names("Pat")
    info.set_addresses("26 Explorer, Punta Gorda, FL")
    info.set_ages("28")
    info.set_numbers("941-245-0266")

    # displays new values
    print "Name:", info.get_names()
    print "Address:", info.get_addresses()
    print "Age:", info.get_ages()
    print "Phone number:", info.get_numbers
    print 

    # stores new values again
    info.set_names("Motley")
    info.set_addresses("11 Scotland Ave, Edison, NJ")
    info.set_ages("49")
    info.set_numbers("732-709-3409")

    # displays newest values
    print "Name:", info.get_names()
    print "Address:", info.get_addresses()
    print "Age:", info.get_ages()
    print "Phone number:", info.get_numbers

main()
```

When I run this code, for all the phone numbers, it displays "main.PersonalInfo instance at 0x0297BB70>>". This is for an intro to computer programming class and I honestly do not understand where I went wrong. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: For one, [you're using setters and getters in Python](https://archive.org/details/SeanKellyRecoveryfromAddiction).

Comment: Also, initial double underscores are bad. If you need to ask whether or not you need to use them, then you don't need to use them.

Comment: Don't use getters and setters. [Python is not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html).

Comment: I would suggest you'll read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6618176/1982962), it will save you a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to actually *call* the method. Note the parens:

```
print "Phone number:", info.get_numbers()
```