# Python: method with variable name for setting value of an object

Tags: python, class, variables, object, methods

Let's have a simple class with values and methods to set them:

```
class Object:
  def __init__(self, id):
      self.__id = id
      self.__value1 = None
      self.__value2 = None
      ... etc

  def set_value1(self, value1):
      self.__value1 = value1
  def set_value2(self, value2):
      self.__value2 = value2
      ... etc
```

Can I somehow merge these .set_valueX(valueX) -functions to be one, how does that happen and is it easily done without import libraries?

Comment: So is it possible or do I have to write the same repeating .set_value() functions for every __init__ separately?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using setatter:

```
class obj(object):

    def __setter(self,**kwargs):
        key,value = kwargs.items()[0]
        setattr(self,"__"+key,value)

    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id
        self.__value1 = None
        self.__value2 = None
        #You should assign setter as the set funciton like this:
        self.set_value1 = self.__setter
        self.set_value2= self.__setter
        #and so on...
```

The **init** method could be done shorter, using the same technique.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to compromise and use one function that handles the logic for all setters, you can do

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._value1 = 1
        self._value2 = 2
        self._value3 = 3

    def set_value(self, attr, value):
        setattr(x, attr, value)
```

and access each method setter via

```
test_obj = Test()
test_obj.set_value("_value1", 10)
```

However, I wouldn't recommend doing either approach. Instead, you may want to use getters and setters via @property decorators.

It is a more "Pythonic" approach and more information can be found in

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score 0):

I'll preface my answer by saying that getters and setters are not very pythonic and seem in this case unnecessary. If you need to customize the get/set behavior consider using properties ([Python @property versus getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/python-property-versus-getters-and-setters)), otherwise there's no reason not to get and set in the typical way (`obj.foo = 'bar'`, `x = obj.foo`).

But I suppose if you really wanted to...a little `__getattr__` magic could do it:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.__id = id
        self.__value1 = None
        self.__value2 = None

    def _setter(self, name):
        def set(value):
            setattr(self, name, value)
        return set

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name.startswith('set_'):
            varname = name.split('_', 1)[-1]
            return self._setter('__' + varname)
        return super(A, self).__getattr__(name)
```

allows for...

```
In [1]: a = A('123')

In [2]: a.set_value1(5)

In [3]: a.__value1
Out[3]: 5

In [4]: a.set_value2(7)

In [5]: a.__value2
Out[5]: 7
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple enough to do, though it would help a lot to know why you are trying to do it.  The most Pythonic approach would possibly be to have a metaclass that creates all your accessor functions.  If you were trying to do this right, I would look up the python `property` paradigm.  However, if all of your accessor functions are identical, why do you need separate functions for them?  You can easily just set values via:

```
x = Object()
x.value = value
```

... So long as you dispense with the entirely unnecessary double-underscore, at least.  If you really need to alter every call to every attribute, you can override `__setattr__` ([Python Data Model Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)). As a side note, in every group I've worked with, the __variable approach has been highly discouraged.  It doesn't stop anyone from actually accessing the value (which you can do via `instance._Object__value1`), but it makes subclassing horrible down the line.

If you want to just do the same pre-processing for every property get or set, you could always do something like:

```
class Object:
   _ATTR_NAMES = ('value1', 'value2', ...)
   def __init__(self):
      for name in self._ATTR_NAMES:
          setattr(self, "_" + name, None)

   def set_attr(self, name, value):
      if name in self._ATTR_NAMES:
         setattr(self, name[1:], value)
      else:
         raise AttributeError("No attribute named %s found"%name)
```

Python's setattr is a function that sets a property with a given name on the attribute.  In this case, you can simply have a list of properties, set them based on that, and retrieve them based on that using the corresponding 'getattr' function.  Again though, I am wary of your reasons for doing this.  Typically explicit is better than implicit.  It's seldom hard to just make an extra get/set function that makes referencing much more clear.

If you truly must, you can also generate get/set functions using techniques very similar to the ones I just showed for properties (i.e., create functions on the fly that wrap `set_attr`), but again, it usually makes code much harder to maintain and read.  I would avoid many of these techniques unless you really have a strong and clear need to do so.  If you really have to do it, something like this would work:

```
class Object:
   _ATTR_NAMES = ('value1', 'value2', ...)
   def __init__(self):
      for name in self._ATTR_NAMES:
          setattr(self, "_" + name, None)

   def _set_attr(self, name, value):
      if name in self._ATTR_NAMES:
         setattr(self, name[1:], value)
      else:
         raise AttributeError("No attribute named %s found"%name)

# This binds named set functions to the class
for name in Object._ATTR_NAMES:
   def tempSetter(self, value):
       self._set_attr(name, value)
   setattr('set_'+name, tempSetter)
del name
del tempSetter
```

This is a hacky way of doing it.  It is more elegant to do this sort of processing in a metaclass.  However, as it takes a lot of background to understand, I'm going to skip that.  If you need to do pre-processing before each set function, it is generally much preferred to do something along the lines of:

```
def _preprocessing(self, value):
   # Do something here
   return value

def set_value1(self, value):
   value = self._preprocessing(value)
   self._value1 = value

def set_value2(self, value):
   value = self._preprocessing(value)
   self._value2 = value
```

Finally, if all you are worried about is the time to generate boilerplate get/set functions, then just write a script that writes the skeleton of your Python class as a text file.  I have these types of scripts that outline my unit test cases based on the original modules.  Or have a script macro in your text editor.  Code is read many more times than it is written, so don't make complex code just to save a few keystrokes.