# Call a function without ()

Tags: python

Can I somehow call a function without the `()`? Maybe abusing the magic methods such as `__call__()` somehow?

I'd like to be able to something similar to

`from IPython import embed as qq`

but call `embed()` only via `qq` rather than `qq()`

This is more out of curiosity, and as a learning exercise for python, rather than practical purposes.

Comment: You can't. `__call__` is used to make something callable, but you still need to actually use the call syntax to actually do so.

Comment: Well, technically you could do it in the repl by abusing `__repr__`, but this would of course not work outside of the interactive interpreter. Or by abusing `__getattr__`, which of course only works for attributes of a class.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the REPL (the Python shell), then you can hack your way around this, because the REPL will call `repr()` on objects for you (which in turn invokes their `__repr__` method):

```
from IPython import embed

class WrappedFunctionCall(object):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn
    def __repr__(self):
        self.fn()
        return ""  # `__repr__` must return a string

qq = WrappedFunctionCall(embed)

# Typing "qq" will invoke embed now and load iPython.
```

But really, you should **not** be doing this!

And of course, it won't work outside of the REPL, because there won't be anything to call `__repr__` in that case. Obviously, passing arguments isn't "supported" either.

Answer (score 1):

`__call__` will be invoked only if the function is invoked with `()`. If the function is in a class, then you can use `@property` decorator, to do something like this

```
import math

class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    @property
    def area(self):
        return math.pi * (self.radius ** 2)

print(Circle(5).area)
# 78.53981633974483
```

Read more about getter and setter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6618002/1903116)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn, play around with Python.

```
In [1]: def foo():
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [2]: foo
Out[2]: <function __main__.foo>

In [3]: foo()

In [4]: bar = foo

In [5]: bar
Out[5]: <function __main__.foo>

In [6]: bar()
```

As you see, `foo` will not *call* the function, it will *return* it. And that is a good thing becaus you can pass it as an argument and assign it, for example `bar = foo`.

Answer (score 0):

In pure Python, the only way I can think of is to use an object and a property:

```
>>> class Wtf(object):
...     @property
...     def yadda(self):
...         print "Yadda"
... 
>>> w = Wtf()
>>> w.yadda
Yadda
>>>
```

Else you might want to check IPython's doc on how to define your own custom "magic" commands: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/custommagics.html

Answer (score 0):

You *can* call the function foo without using () (on *that* function):

```
def call_function(fun_name,*args):
    return fun_name(*args)

def foo(a,b):
    return a+b

print call_function(foo,1,2)

# Prints 3
```

Note that this answer isn't entirely serious, but it does contain a snippet of interesting Python code.