# Understand classes in Python?

Tags: python, class, typeerror, derived-class

I have to define a class `Vehicle`. Each object of the class has two attributes, `license` (license plate) and `year` (year of construction), and two methods that return those attributes.

In addition, I have to define a class `Car`, a derived class of `Vehicle`, that has two more attributes, `dis` (displacement) and `max` (maximum number of people in the car), with methods to know the latter two.

This is the code I tried to write:

```
class vehicle:
  def __init__(self,License_plate,Year):
    self.license = License_plate
    self.year = Year
  def year(self):
    return self.year
  def license(self):
    return self.license

class car(vehicle):
  def __init__(self,License_plate,Year,Displacement,maximum):
    veicolo.__init__(self, License_plate, Year)
    self.dis = Displacement
    self.max = maximum
  def displacement(self):
    return self.dis
  def max(self):
    return self.max



a = vehicle('ASDFE',1234)             #This is how I tried to run it 
a.year()                              #Here I got an ERROR :
a.license()                           #TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
b = car('ASDERTWWW',1234,7000,2340)
b.displacement()
b.max()
```

I have some problem with class in Python. I can not understand the use of a derived class.

Comment: You are using the same names for the attribute and the method; this is a very bad idea. In fact, you don't need the methods at all; you can just access the attribute directly (or use a `@property` - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6618002/3001761).

Comment: http://www.memonic.com/user/pneff/folder/development/id/1ttgT

Comment: Yaay ! I understood my problem ! Thank man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python we don't need getters and setters.

```
class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self, year):
        self.year = year

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, name, year):
        super(Car, self).__init__(year)
        self.name = name 

a = Vehicle(1995)
print a.year
b = Car("test", 1992)
print b.name
print b.year
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a method and a variable with the same name. When you call `a.year()` you are trying to call the `year` variable.

One solution would be to rename one of them (either the variable to `_year` or the method to `getYear`). Alternatively you could just access the variables directly. Nothing is private in python so you can just do `>>> a.year` -> `1234`