# Vector Class Problems

Tags: python

I have a class of objects called Vector. I am going to include the class early on as I think it is necessary, if not, please tell me so i can delete it immediately (to avoid DV).

```
class Vec:
    """
    A vector has two fields:
    D - the domain (a set)
    f - a dictionary mapping (some) domain elements to field elements
        elements of D not appearing in f are implicitly mapped to zero
    """
    def __init__(self, labels, function):
        self.D = labels
        self.f = function

    __getitem__ = getitem
    __setitem__ = setitem
    __neg__ = neg
    __rmul__ = scalar_mul #if left arg of * is primitive, assume it's a scalar

    def __mul__(self,other):
        #If other is a vector, returns the dot product of self and other
        if isinstance(other, Vec):
            return dot(self,other)
        else:
            return NotImplemented  #  Will cause other.__rmul__(self) to be invoked

    def __truediv__(self,other):  # Scalar division
        return (1/other)*self

    __add__ = add

    def __radd__(self, other):
        "Hack to allow sum(...) to work with vectors"
        if other == 0:
            return self

    def __sub__(a,b):
        "Returns a vector which is the difference of a and b."
        return a+(-b)

    __eq__ = equal

    def is_almost_zero(self):
        s = 0
        for x in self.f.values():
            if isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float):
                s += x*x
            elif isinstance(x, complex):
                s += x*x.conjugate()
            else: return False
        return s < 1e-20

    def __str__(v):
        "pretty-printing"
        D_list = sorted(v.D, key=repr)
        numdec = 3
        wd = dict([(k,(1+max(len(str(k)), len('{0:.{1}G}'.format(v[k], numdec))))) if isinstance(v[k], int) or isinstance(v[k], float) else (k,(1+max(len(str(k)), len(str(v[k]))))) for k in D_list])
        s1 = ''.join(['{0:>{1}}'.format(str(k),wd[k]) for k in D_list])
        s2 = ''.join(['{0:>{1}.{2}G}'.format(v[k],wd[k],numdec) if isinstance(v[k], int) or isinstance(v[k], float) else '{0:>{1}}'.format(v[k], wd[k]) for k in D_list])
        return "\n" + s1 + "\n" + '-'*sum(wd.values()) +"\n" + s2

    def __hash__(self):
        "Here we pretend Vecs are immutable so we can form sets of them"
        h = hash(frozenset(self.D))
        for k,v in sorted(self.f.items(), key = lambda x:repr(x[0])):
            if v != 0:
                h = hash((h, hash(v)))
        return h

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Vec(" + str(self.D) + "," + str(self.f) + ")"

    def copy(self):
        "Don't make a new copy of the domain D"
        return Vec(self.D, self.f.copy())
```

I now have to write procedures so that, it works?.
I have completed this assignment, i had 8/9. This is great but i need 9/9 because its being used in another assignment. (This is to clarify that i'm not mindlessly posting homework questions on here.)

```
def getitem(v,k):
    kthelement = 0
    try:
        kthelement = v.f[k]
    except Exception:
        kthelement = 0
    return kthelement



def setitem(v,k,val):
    v.f[k] = val


def equal(u,v):
    result = False
    unmatched_item = set(v.f.items()) ^ set(u.f.items())
    if len(unmatched_item) == 0:
        result = True
    return result
```

The first 2 are fine and work. This third one is the problem.
It works sometimes, then some some comparisons it returns False when True or the converse.

Also if,

```
D = {'a','b','c'}
v1 = Vec(D, {'a': 1})
v2 = Vec(D, {'a':1, 'b':0}
```

Then v1 == v2

Could someone help me out on this last one please.

Comment: Nevermind this comment, sorry, I get what you mean.

Comment: Why are you defining `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__eq__`, etc outside the class like that?

Comment: `v1 == v2` --> `False` because `unmatched_item` is `{('b', 0)}` which has a `len()` of `1`, so `len(unmatched_item) == 0` is `False`.

Comment: In my code it does return False, but in terms of vectors, v1 == v2 is actually true, because technically speaking my domain is 3d space. by default, if an element is not specified a map then it is mapped to 0.( i.e (x,y,0) 2d plane in 3d space)  I think i should have mentioned this in my post. For the procedure to be marked as correct, Vec({'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'a':0}) == Vec({'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'b':0}) has to return True.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that, as far as I can tell, you never implemented the mechanism by which `0` is returned for items in the domain. There are probably many ways to fix this, one way is to construct the dictionary in the constructor:

```
def __init__(self, labels, function):
    self.D = labels
    self.f = {label: function.get(label, 0) for label in D}
```

I haven't fully thought through all the implications on the other parts of your function though, but if you intend `f` to store a `dict` containing *only* the parts of the dict `function` which are in `D`, then this implements that.

That said, if you intend for `f` to be something the user can manipulate directly, you may want to implement it as a property (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/python-property-versus-getters-and-setters)), in which case your original `__init__` would work, and you'd move the dictionary comprehension from my version of `__init__` into the `f` property setter.

Also, I should add that I'm assuming from the comment that you want to *exclude* anything in `function` that is not in `D`, so you'll notice that using your original code:

```
D = {'a','b','c'}
v1 = Vec(D, {'a': 1})
v2 = Vec(D, {'a':1, 'b':0})

print(v1 == v2)

v3 = Vec(D, {'a': 1, 'e': 4})
print(v1 == v3)
```

Returns:

```
False
False
```

But with the dict comprehension, it returns:

```
True
True
```

If you would prefer to throw an error if labels not in the domain are found (or allow them in the `.f` property), you'll have to handle that situation as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. This returns the desired result.

```
def equal(u,v):
    counter = 0
    for k in u.D:
        if v[k] == u[k]:
            counter += 1
    return counter == len(u.D)
```