# Use a function to write different class attributes

Tags: python, attributes

I'd like to create a function that writes to an attribute in a Python class, but be able to decide whether the attribute should be written.

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
        self.b = None

    def write_attrib(self,which_attrib,value):
        # perform a check here
        which_attrib = value

    def write_a(self,value):
        self.write_attrib(self.a, value)

    def write_b(self,value):
        self.write_attrib(self.b, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t  = Test()
    t.write_a(5)
    t.write_b(4)
    print(t.a, t.b)
```

Now this will result in both values being `None`, so they haven't been touched by the function.

I'd like to do this approach so I can do some checks in `write_attrib` before writing the attribute and I don't have to write these checks twice (but would like to make the convenience functions `write_a` and `write_b` available).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not just use e.g. `setattr(t, 'a', 5)` (or `setattr(self, which_attrib, value)` in `write_attrib`), or if you need to do something specific when particular attributes are set implement a `@property` or even `__setattr__`? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, maybe I just wasn't aware of the magic method __setattr__, but pretty much before writing the attribute I'd like to do some error checking to ensure consistency. If I'd change __setattr__ this would work for all attributes (I don't want that), but I can use @property to do this only for some? How would that work?

Comment: You could implement `__setattr__` to only apply the checking to a list of specified attributes, and ignore the rest. If you want to implement properties, read e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build on my comment, you can implement `__setattr__` to only validate the properties you specify:

```
class Test(object):

    VALIDATED = {'a', 'b'}

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
        self.b = None

    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        if attr in self.VALIDATED:
            pass  # add your checking
        super(Test, self).__setattr__(attr, val)
```

Alternatively, you can implement a `@property` for the attributes you want to validate, managing access to a *private-by-convention* attribute (with a leading underscore in the identifier):

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
        self.b = None

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, val):
        # add your checking here
        self._a = val

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, val):
        # add your checking here
        self._b = val
```

The former is probably neater if you have many attributes with the same validation rules, the latter if you have fewer attributes and/or different validation rules for each one. Both allow you to have clean attribute access, without getters or setters (see e.g. [Python @property versus getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6618002/3001761)).

Comment: The `a` in `self.a` is actually a reference to the property which sets `self._a = None` when `Test` is instantiated. Is that what's happening?

Comment: @xyres yes: `self.a = None` calls `self.a.setter(None)` which sets `self._a = None`.

Comment: Thanks. That's really creative.

Comment: @xyres no problem. You *might* assign directly to the private attribute `_a` if, for instance ,`None` would be a valid starting value but not one you want the user to set. If you're interested in this, I answered a similar question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29770260/3001761

Answer (score 1):

Use `property`

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = None

    @property:
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        # Do your validation here
        self._a = value
```

Comment: Note that assigning to `self.a` rather than `self._a` in `__init__` means that the validation runs there, too, which is generally good practice. It also minimises the code changes if you introduce properties for regular attributes later on.