# Is there a function like __getattr__ that gets called for class variables?

Tags: python, python-2.7, getattr

I want to redefine an object's get function so that I can intercept when any attribute is requested. Using the **getattr** function, it doesn't catch when existing variables (eg. attr1 in this case) are requested. Is there a way around this, so I can run a function when attr1 is requested?

```
class Test(object):
    attr1 = 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr2 = 1
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print 'GETATTR', attr
a = Test()
a.attr1
a.attr2
a.attr3
```

Output:

```
GETATTR attr3
```

I'd like to see GETATTR attr1 and GETATTR attr2 in the output too.

Comment: If you want to run code when your objects' attributes are accessed you might like [properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/python-property-versus-getters-and-setters), although class-level properties require [some extra code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927444/is-there-a-function-like-getattr-that-gets-called-for-class-variables)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a matter of class or instance variables.  It's a matter of whether the attribute exists or not; your `attr1` exists but the others do not.  (What you do with `attr2` does not create an attribute; you're just creating a local variable and throwing it away.  If you do `self.attr2 = 1`, you will see that `__getattr__` is not called for `attr2` either.)

As [documented](https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), `__getattr__` is called "when an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places (i.e. it is not an instance attribute nor is it found in the class tree for self)".  As also documented in the same place, there is another magic method `__getattribute__` which is always called, even when the attribute does exist.

Comment: Ah great, that answers my question perfectly, thank you

Comment: Yes sorry, I noticed that bug in my code - Ill fix the question