# override __getattr__ for methods and not variables

Tags: python

i want the next code to work

```
class A(object):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print item
        return self.item
    def x(self):
        print 4
a = A()
a.x()
```

and the output will ber

```
x
4
```

i know its not working becuase x is like a static variable and not an instance variable.
I saw this [__getattr__ for static/class variables in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155436/getattr-for-static-class-variables-in-python) and it doesn't seem to work in my case
how can it be done?

thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override \_\_getattr\_\_ in Python without breaking the default behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405590/how-do-i-override-getattr-in-python-without-breaking-the-default-behavior)

Comment: its completly unrelated

Comment: There's not much difference between methods and attributes in new-style classes. `__getattr__` only gets involved if the actual attribute cannot be found (and `x` **can** be found in this case). *"i want the next code to work"* - it **does work**, that's what's supposed to happen.

Comment: @kill129 No, it solves your question if you read the answer carefully. I quote: `__getattr__ is only called as a last resort  i.e. if there are no attributes in the instance that match the name [...] However, unlike __getattr__, __getattribute__ will be called first`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a function like \_\_getattr\_\_ that gets called for class variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927444/is-there-a-function-like-getattr-that-gets-called-for-class-variables)

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of obvious problems with your code:

```
class A(object):

    def __getattr__(self, item):  # 1
        print item
        return self.item  # 2

    def x(self):  # 1 again
        print 4
```

1. `__getattr__` will only be invoked if `item` cannot be found the normal way. For `item == 'x'`, therefore, it is never invoked.
2. Which is probably just as well, since `self.item` looks for the attribute `item`, not the attribute corresponding to whatever is assigned to `item`. This doesn't exist, so would invoke `__getattr__`. If you try `A().y()` you'll get `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.

Instead, I think you want to use `__getattribute__`, which is always invoked. You need to be careful not to get the same runtime error, though; here I avoid it by calling the superclass implementation of `__getattribute__`, the naïve way of calling `getattr(self, item)` would fail:

```
class A(object):

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        print item
        return super(A, self).__getattribute__(item)

    def x(self):
        print 4
```

Which gives:

```
>>> A().x()
x
4
>>> A().y()
y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __getattribute__
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'y'
```

Note that both `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` apply equally to attributes and methods (which are, more or less, just callable attributes).