# Python can't set attribute on non-persistent property

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to set a non-persistent property on a model. I have tried the following:

```
class class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, db_index=True)

    @property
    def client_id(self):
        return self.client_id
```

Then:

```
user = User.objects.create(email='123', client_id=123)
print(user.client_id)
```

I get the error: **can't set attribute**. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define a setter function for your property too, right now, it is read-only (see, e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/python-property-versus-getters-and-setters) question).

```
class class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, db_index=True)

    @property
    def client_id(self):
        return self.internal_client_id

    @client_id.setter
    def client_id(self, value):
        self.internal_client_id = value
```

Note that I renamed `self.client_id` to `self.internal_client_id`, because otherwise, you would be calling the getter and setter functions recursively - the name of the internal variable needs to be different from the property's name.

Of course, if you need to use `self.client_id` (e.g. because of inheritance), you can also rename the property itself.

Comment: I did try that but I got ``maximum recursion depth exceeded``

Comment: That's because your internal variable has the same name as your property, so you'd call the setter recursively.

Comment: It should, if `self._client_id` exists (don't forget to update the setter too)

Comment: If it really looks like this why bothering to write those two property methods at all?  Why not simply set and get that attribute. The code has no real effect.

Comment: @BlackJack In this case, yes. However, properties do have certain advantages over simple attributes (e.g. allowing you to enforce certain constraints on values, etc.)