# AtributeError: can't set attribute for python list property

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-decorators, python-docx

I'm working with the `python-docx` library from a forked [version](https://pypi.org/project/bayoo-docx/), and I'm having an issue with editing the elements list as it is defined as a property.

```py
# docx.document.Document
@property
def elements(self):
    return self._body.elements
```

I tried to go with the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34179815/4171008) but the error *`AtributeError: can't set attribute`* still popping out.

Next thing I tried is adding the `setter` to the attribute derived from `self._body` and editing the code:

```py
# docx.blkcntnr.BlockItemContainer

@property
def elements(self):
    """
    A list containing the elements in this container (paragraph and tables), in document order.
    """
    return [element(item,self.part) for item in self._element.getchildren()]
```

I've tried to add the `setter` in both levels but ended up again with the error *`AtributeError: can't set attribute`*

**The `setter` I wrote:**

```py
@elements.setter
def elements(self, value):
    return value
```

The implementation I tired:

```py
elements_list = docx__document.elements
elem_list = []
docx__document.elements = elements_list = elem_list
```

The main problem with that code is `docx__document.elements` still contains all the elements that are supposed to have been deleted!

Editing the library was like this:

```py
# Inside docx.document.Document
@property
def elements(self):
    return self._body.elements

@elements.setter
def elements(self, value=None):
    self._body.elements = value
    gc.collect()
    return value
```

The other part:

```py
# Inside docx.blkcntnr.BlockItemContainer

@property
def elements(self):
    """
    A list containing the elements in this container (paragraph and tables), in document order.
    """
    return [element(item,self.part) for item in self._element.getchildren()]


@elements.setter
def elements(self, value):
    """
    A list containing the elements in this container (paragraph and tables), in document order.
    """
    return value
```

### Related question [Update]

---

If I did add a `setter` for this `property` :

```
# docx.document.Document

@property
def elements(self):
    return self._body.elements
```

Should I add also a `setter` for the `property`:

```py
# docx.blkcntnr.BlockItemContainer

@property
def elements(self):
    """
    A list containing the elements in this container (paragraph and tables), in document order.
    """
    return [element(item,self.part) for item in self._element.getchildren()]
```

Because the value of `document.elemetns` is actually the value from `document._body.elements`, am I right?

Any help would appreciate it!

Comment: Hi @Jasmijn the code used and the error is added also with steps I took with this issue.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. Unfortunately it's still not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi @Jasmijn again, can you check the question now? If it is good can you upvote it also?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but it seems to me you're going about it the wrong way. The `elements` getter returns a list-comprehension of objects composed of its children (`return [element(..) for item in self._element.getchildren()]`). The getter always creates a new list from the children, so setting the attribute "element" itself to an empty list will not delete the children. I suggest poking around the instance's `_element` attribute, perhaps check where `def getchildren()` gets you to. Look at what is used to _create_ the list, instead of the list itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main "Attribute Error" issue, @Jasmijn already covered... the setter actually needs to set something.

In regards to how to provide a setter for `elements`:

First we need to figure out where `elements` comes from:

- `Document.elements` comes from `[Document]._body.elements`
- `[Document]._body.elements` comes from `_Body`, which inherits `BlockItemContainer.elements`
- `BlockItemContainer.elements` builds its elements list dynamically from `[BlockItemContainer]._element.getchildren()`
- `[BlockItemContainer]._element` is equal to `[Document]._element.body`
- `[Document]._element` comes from extending `ElementProxy`, and is the first argument passed to Document's constructor

In a very round-a-bout way, given `element` passed to `Document`, the document's `elements` are derived from: `element.body.getchildren()`. (A bit tricky tracking down the lookup chain, but that's just what you get when there's a lot of abstraction, or perhaps poor object oriented design)

Now to track down what exactly `getchildren()` does:

- Looks like the `element` passed to `Document` is from the included `oxml` package
- `oxml` is itself a wrapper around `lxml`
- Looks like the relevant classes are actually in Cython. As far as I can tell, the `_Element` class is where `getchildren()` is ultimately defined (`etree.pyx`)
- `getchildren()` calls `_collectChildren` (`apihelpers.pxi`), which gives you an idea of how the internal element structure is setup

Given that the root implementation is Cython is going to complicate things, but I see that the `_Element` class implements some additional methods which you could make use of, in particular: `clear()` and `extend()`.

So a possible implementation (which I've tested and appears to work):

```py
# inside docx.document.Document
@elements.setter
def elements(self, lst):
    cython_el = self._element.body
    cython_el.clear()
    cython_el.extend(lst)
```

I'll disagree with @Jasmijn here and say you *don't* need to provide a setter for `BlockItemContainer` as well, since that's a private class.

You could also expose other `_Element` methods directly on the `Document` object if desired, like `clear()`.

Comment: Impressive. I got lost somewhere in the process of chasing proxy object to proxy object and wrapper library to wrapper library, all of which seemed to be either poorly documented or completely undocumented. As for our disagreement, that's fair. I was thinking only about a setter on Document that delegated the actual work of changing the elements to `self._element` which would be my preference.

Answer (score 2):

First a word of warning: if you edit a library, those changes will be wiped away if/when you upgrade the library.

While your question is still not reproducible, I can see now what the problem is.

Setters need to mutate some kind of state to be useful. They don't return values.

```
# Inside docx.document.Document

@elements.setter
def elements(self, value):
    self._body.elements = value


# Inside docx.blkcntnr.BlockItemContainer

@elements.setter
def elements(self, value):
    # FIXME
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out how to implement `docx.blkcntnr.BlockItemContainer.elements.setter` in a way that neatly replaces the XML tree.

Since it looks like you want to use it to wipe a document clear, why not simply instantiate a new `Document` instead, like so?

```
docx__document = docx.Document()
```

Comment: Using `docx__document = docx.Document()` will still create an object in the memory and that is the opposite of what I'm trying.
I'm trying to clear all the contents to save some space in the memory

Comment: `> warning: if you edit a library, those changes will be wiped away if/when you upgrade the library. ` 
I know that, I'm planning to push the update to its repo

Comment: In that case, you could try `del docx__document` or `docx__document = None`.

Comment: This will lead to another problem, the `garbage collector` is not actually -I assume- doing its job because even if I call it manually the memory usage is not dropping

Comment: Hi @Jasmijn I've updated the question, if you can help with the last update I would really appreciate it and I can approve the answer, Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I've given you the best answer I can with the information you provided. Unless and until I can reproduce your actual problem, there is nothing more for me to do except speculate. And it's not even clear to me what your real problem is. Why do you need to reclaim memory?

Comment: I mean the other part under `Related question [Update]` do you have any idea? @jasmijn

Comment: Oh the answer to that is yes.