# Calculate attribute if it doesn't exist

Tags: python

I am trying to access an attribute that shouldn't be created in the `__init__` method of my class but can be calculated by calling another method. I am trying to make it so that if I try to access the attribute and it does not exist it will be automatically calculated. However, I don't want it to be recalculated if the attribute does exist, even if the value would be different. For example:

```
class SampleObject(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def calculate_total(self):
        self.total = self.a + self.b

sample = SampleObject(1, 2)
print sample.total   # should print 3
sample.a = 2
print sample.total   # should print 3
sample.calculate_total()
print sample.total   # should print 4
```

My best solution so far is to make a get_total() method that does what I need.

```
class SampleObject2(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def calculate_total(self):
        self.total = self.a + self.b

    def get_total(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'total'):
            return self.total
        else:
            self.calculate_total()
            return self.total

sample2 = SampleObject2(1, 2)
print sample2.get_total() # prints 3
sample2.a = 2
print sample2.get_total() # prints 3
sample2.calculate_total()
print sample2.get_total() # prints 4
```

This is working fine, but I have read that using getters in python is discouraged and I was hoping to avoid calling this function every time I wanted to access the attribute. Is this my best solution, or is there a cleaner, more pythonic way of doing this?

This is an example that I made up. In my actual problem, calculate_total() is a time consuming process that won't necessarily need to be called. So I don't want to execute it in the **init** method.

Comment: Do you purposely want to work with outdated totals until you recalculate manually (the forgetting of which could cause issues)? What if your `get_total` would automatically recalculate whenever the cached value is wrong? Wouldn't that be better?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to use the `@property` decorator. Create a method, that will be accessed like a normal attribute, that does lazy computation:

```
class SampleObject:

    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self._total = None

    @property
    def total(self):
        """Compute or return the _total attribute."""
        if self._total is None:
            self.compute_total()

        return self._total
```

Comment: what's the benefit of lazy computation vs just calling the get_total() method OP created?

Comment: I don't know. (There are many possibly answers, but the OP didn't specify a particular one.) This just meets the OP's criteria. But consider: maybe there's a hardware sensor being read. Maybe the answer depends on the user filling in a form and pressing a button. Maybe OP wants to avoid increasing the load during system startup. Maybe the network isn't online yet. Maybe another process or thread needs to finish...

Answer (score 4):

Pyramid (a Web framework) comes with a `reify` decorator that is similar to `property` (shown by Austin Hastings) but it works a little differently: the function is only executed once, and after that, the value returned by the function is always used. It essentially does what Austin's code does, but without having to use a separate attribute: it's a generalization of that pattern.

You probably don't want to use a whole Web framework just for this one decorator, so here is an equivalent one I wrote:

```
import functools

class Descriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __get__(self, inst, type=None):
        val = self.func(inst)
        setattr(inst, self.func.__name__, val)
        return val

def reify(func):
    return functools.wraps(func)(Descriptor(func))
```

Usage:

```
class ReifyDemo:
    @reify
    def total(self):
        """Compute or return the total attribute."""
        print("calculated total")
        return 2 + 2    # some complicated calculation here

r = ReifyDemo()
print(r.total)     # prints 'calculated total 4' because the function was called
print(r.total)     # prints just '4` because the function did not need to be called
```

Comment: It's also unclear why you bothered using `functools.wraps()` on something that is going to become a simple `int` value (in this case) which doesn't have `__name__` or `__doc__` attributes like a function.

Comment: I originally had the `Descriptor` class inside the `reify` function but moved it out so there wouldn't need to be a unique copy of the class for each decorated function. But I neglected to make the other necessary changes; obviously the closure won't work once I've done that. How embarrassing; I'll fix that. The reason I used `functool.wraps()` is so the function's doc will be available in the class's help.

Comment: I considered not using it, but even after it's been used on an instance, the class still has the original descriptor, and it is useful to have the docstring when you do `help()` on the class.

Comment: The `ReifyDemo` class? What if you use `reify()` on more than one of its methods?

Comment: Each method has its own `Descriptor` instance, so the docstring of each underlying method is preserved.

Comment: So you're applying it to each instance of your `Descriptor` class? Seems odd to be `functools.wrap`ping an instance of something other than a function/method.

Comment: Python doesn't seem to care.  :-)

Comment: After some more thought, I suspect that it may be intentional and have something to do with the design and implementation of descriptors and properties (see [_What's New in Python 2.2_](https://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/whatsnew/sect-rellinks.html#SECTION000320000000000000000)).