# Python subclassing and parent value assignment

Tags: python, class, flask

Apologies if the subject isn't accurate, I wasn't sure how else to phrase it.

I'm learning to work with Python classes. I created a class that I want to be able to subclass. The problem is that some parts of the class are dependent on variables set in the class, and those default to empty values (the intent is to define them when subclassed). For example:

config.py:

```
class Config(object):
    VAR1 = ''
    if VAR1 == 'somevalue':
        VAR2 = VAR1 + 'something'
    else:
        VAR2 = VAR1
```

subclass.py:

```
from config import Config
class Production(Config):
    VAR1 = 'value1'
```

The problem here is that VAR2 doesn't pick up the subclassed VAR1. I understand why this isn't working as I want, my question is: **Is it possible to do it this way (or in a similar fashion)? And, if so, how?**

**UPDATE:**

I worked out a way to this, but it still requires more typing than I'd prefer--the variations to the function below are minimal and are based on variables that are explicitly set when `Config` is subclassed. So it would be nice to have these values (VAL2 from the parent class) set automatically based on the context of the subclass (the value of VAL1 when `Config` is subclassed), rather than having to explicitly set them.

config.py:

```
class Config(object)
    VAR1 = ''
    VAR2 = ''

def set_var2(val):
    if val == 'somevalue':
        VAR2 = val + 'value2'
    else:
        VAR2 = 'value2'

    return VAR2
```

subclass.py:

```
from config import Config, set_var2
class Production(Config):
    VAR1 = 'value1'
    VAR2 = set_var2(VAL1)
```

Comment: What do you expect `Production.VAR1`, `Production.VAR2`, and `Config.VAR2` to be?

Comment: This is a very abnormal example.  You have no methods, and no class instances.  What you have is static class code that sets class variables.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit: Read to the end: _I understand why this isn't working as I want..._  He *wants* the `if`-`else` blocks to be evaluated after `VAR1` is set in `Production`, but he knows why his own code doesn't work.

Comment: @zondo Yep, I read it. I'm trying to help, but I want to know what the expectation is. Thanks.

Comment: @TomKarzes This is only intended to configure a Flask app. As I've read, this seems to be a common pattern (and follows an example at [Flask's site](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#development-production)). Am I thinking about it wrong? I'm asking for help because I'm not sure how to do what I mentioned.

Comment: @TomKarzes You could add whatever methods you want to the classes, and that wouldn't affect the question of how to have class variables initialized in this way.

Comment: I see.  What you need to understand about class code is that it is executed once, when the class definition is processed.  In this example, both `VAR1` and `VAR2` are set in `Config` when the class is defined, and `VAR1` is set in `Production` when that class is defined.  `Production` does not contain its own copy of `VAR2`, but merely inherits it from `Config`.

Comment: @TomKarzes I understand, and therein lies the problem. I'm searching for a way to achieve the objective I mentioned, even if it means doing things a little differently.

Comment: The only thing I could think of was to have an inherited class method that's called to set the class variables.  But I believe such a method would have to be called after the class is defined.  It will work though.  If you're interested, I can post an example.

Comment: Thanks. I'm interested.

Comment: Ok, I posted it.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to access an attribute (that is, `obj.foo`) and have it perform a last-minute computation. This way, you can evaluate the results of any subclassing that may have occurred after your original class was defined.

This is what the `@property` decorator is for - hide code behind an attribute name. See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35328795/calculate-attribute-if-it-doesnt-exist/35328846#35328846) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this using class methods.  I would have liked to put the class method calls inside the class itself, at the top level, but that doesn't work since the class does not yet exist.  So instead, you need to call the class method after the class has been defined.  But it does work.

Here's an example definition (and configuration) of `Config`:

```
class Config(object):
    @classmethod
    def set_vars(cls, var1):
        cls.VAR1 = var1

        if var1 == 'somevalue':
            cls.VAR2 = var1 + 'something'
        else:
            cls.VAR2 = var1

Config.set_vars('')
```

And here's how you could define cond configure `Production`:

```
class Production(Config):
    pass

Production.set_vars('value1')
```

The class method `set_vars` sets `VAR1` and `VAR2` as class variables in the class it's called from.  The parent class is unchanged.

Comment: This didn't work. Maybe this is because Flask is explicitly importing the class object (`Production`) and expects the variables to be set there (such as `VAR1 = 'value1')? ... I did work out a way different but similar way to minimize code duplication, though, in a way that Flask can consume the configurations--but it's not exactly what I was hoping the end result would be. I'll post that code shortly.

Comment: No, it will absolutely, positively work. The result is identical to what you would get if you manually assigned the variables. Python can not tell the difference. I just explicitly tested importing the classes into a third file, with both Python 2 and Python 3, and they were fully configured. You must have made a mistake. I will be able to spot the error in about a minute if you can show a minimal example using my solution that doesn't work.

Comment: By the way, it should be very, very easy for you to debug this.  All you need to do to see if class `Foo` has been configured properly is create a file that imports it (just as Flask does), then just print `Foo.VAR1`, `Foo.VAR2`, etc.  Get it?  Do you see how simple this is?  You will immediately see your mistake.  Just put some effort into it.  Try to *understand* what's going on before giving up.

Comment: Thanks for all your input, Tom. I hope you didn't take offense to my response--it seems that you did based on the condescending tone of your last response. ... And yes, I did print the var from outside the subclass and the value was set correctly--however, as I mentioned, **Flask** didn't import it. ... I had already deleted the code I tested earlier, but I set it up again and it is working--so clearly I made a mistake somewhere with my last attempt.

Comment: Oh, ok, glad it's working.  As I said, it pretty much *has* to work, since what Flask sees will be indistinguishable from what you would obtain if you set the variables manually.  The only possible issue is the name of the class function (I used `set_vars` for the name), but if for some reason that conflicts with something, it can always be renamed.  But it doesn't sound like that's the case here.

Answer (score -1):

Because Python is an object-oriented programming language, the classes you make should always have constructors. These are special methods that initialize the variables inside of the class, and Python uses the `__init__()` method to carry this out. Here's a solution to your predicament.

```
class Config(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.VAR1 = ''
        self.VAR2 = ''

    def assign_var2(self):
        if self.VAR1 == 'somevalue':
            self.VAR2 = self.VAR1 + 'something'
        else:
            self.VAR2 = self.VAR1

class Production(Config):
    def __init__(self):
        self.VAR1 = 'somevalue'
        self.assign_var2()
        print(self.VAR2)

Production()
```

The output of this code is `somevaluesomething`, which essentially demonstrates that by assigning a value to `VAR1`, the value of `VAR2` was also changed. Here's what I did differently:

- **Constructors** – I made constructors for both the Config and the Production class, which allowed me to initialize and access the variables inside. To define class variables, you need to use the `self` keyword to indicate this, so I changed that in your script.
- **Functions** – In order to change the value of `VAR2`, you need to include a function that can do that. The problem is that by just assigning a value to `VAR1` in the Production class, you do nothing because the conditional statement is a part of the Config class. The conditional statement in the Config class is **never** called. In order to effectively call it, you can put it inside a method (`assign_var2`) and then call that method inside the constructor of the Production class. Lastly, for a sanity check, I included `print(self.VAR2)` to make sure the code works.

Comment: You're assuming `VAR1` and `VAR2` shouldn't be class variables; there's nothing in the question to warrant that.