# How can I implement "cached member variables" in python class?

Tags: python

Is there any way to implement the following boilerplates in python classes? I have many variables to be lazy-evaluated and cached..

```
class SomeClass(object):
  def calculate_x(self):
    var = getattr(self, 'x')
    if var:
      return var
    self.x = ....
    return self.x
```

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815110/is-there-a-decorator-to-simply-cache-function-return-values

Comment: See also https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/functional.py#L15

Comment: If you only need to cache a single value, check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/35328997/416467