# Python - what's the difference between @property and setting in __init__()?

Tags: python, properties

Couldn't quite get a straight answer from other threads on this one:

In Python, what's the main difference between using

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x
```

and

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, x):
    self._x = x

  @property
  def x(self):
    return self._x
```

By the looks of it using @property in this way makes x read-only.. but maybe someone has a better answer? Thanks /Fred

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your example, yes this allows you to have read-only attributes. Further, properties can allow you to seem to have more attributes than you actually do. Consider a circle with `.radius` and `.area`. The area can be calculated based on the radius, rather than having to store both

```
import math

class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    @property
    def area(self):
        return math.pi * (self.radius ** 2)
```

Answer (score 7):

The `property` decorator implementation uses the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), which is how we do data encapsulation in Python OOP. A descriptor is:

> In general, a descriptor is an object attribute with “binding
> behavior”, one whose attribute access has been overridden by methods
> in the descriptor protocol. Those methods are `__get__()`, `__set__()`,
> and `__delete__()`. If any of those methods are defined for an object,
> it is said to be a descriptor.

Typically, in other OOP languages you use getters and setters. You'll frequently see people coming from, say, Java writing a Python class like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
    def getX(self):
        return self._x
    def getY(self):
        return self._y
    def setX(self, x):
        self._x = x
    def setY(self, y):
        self._y = y
    def some_method_that_uses_attributes(self):
        return self.getX() + self.getY()
```

This is very much *not* how you would do things in Python. The point of getters and setters is to provide data encapsulation. We encapsulate access to a data attribute by wrapping that in a getter and setter. Then, if we ever want to add something, say, make sure `x` is never set to a value below 10 (as a contrived example), we simply change the way `setX` is implemented, and we don't have to modify the rest of our code. In Python, however, we would write the above class as follows:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def some_method_that_uses_attributes(self):
        return self.x + self.y
```

A person coming from Java might recoil in horror: "You aren't properly encapsulating your class! This will become a maintenance nightmare!"

Nope, because we have descriptors/properties:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self.y = y
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        if val > 10:
            self._x = val
        else:
            raise ValueError("x must be greater than 10")
    def some_method_that_uses_attributes(self):
        return self.x + self.y
```

And now, we don't have to refractor every method that uses `self.x`, like `some_method_that_uses_attributes`. And more importantly, clients of our class don't have a broken interface when we make this change! This is nice because it lets us avoid writing a bunch of boilerplate code, and implementing descriptors is relatively straightfoward in the cases where we *do* need it. Also, this makes our code nice and pretty, without `self.get_this()` and `self.set_that(3)` all over the code, and the much more readable `self.this` and `self.that = 3`

Comment: Don't say that `property` implements descriptor protocol (misleading and incorrect).  Rather, `property` implementation uses descriptor protocol.

Answer (score -2):

Check out this SO post on Python properties - it refers to getters/setters specifically but the answers break down a lot more about them and I believe everything you want to know is in there: [Python @property versus getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/python-property-versus-getters-and-setters)