# Should I use properties or getters and setters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, getter-setter

I know that it is not pythonic to use getters and setters in python. Rather property decorators should be used. But I am wondering about the following scenario -

I have a class initialized with a few instance attributes. Then later on I need to add other instance attributes to the class. If I don't use setters, then I have to write `object.attribute = value` everywhere outside the class. The class will not have the `self.attribute` code. Won't this become a problem when I need to track the attributes of the class (because they are strewn all over the code outside the class)?

Comment: I think you should read this article regarding your subject:
http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php ALso, worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters Just another one, that is quite good. A must, I may say: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/python-property-versus-getters-and-setters

Answer (score 7):

In general, you shouldn't even use properties. Simple attributes work just fine in the vast majority of cases:

```
class X:
    pass
```

```
>>> x = X()
>>> x.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  # ... etc
AttributeError: 'X' object has no attribute 'a'
>>> x.a = 'foo'
>>> x.a
'foo'
```

A property should only be used if you *need* to do some work when accessing an attribute:

```
import random

class X:

    @property
    def a(self):
        return random.random()
```

```
>>> x = X()
>>> x.a
0.8467160913203089
```

If you also need to be able to assign to a property, defining a setter is straightforward:

```
class X:

    @property
    def a(self):
        # do something clever
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        # do something even cleverer
        self._a = value
```

```
>>> x = X()
>>> x.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  # ... etc
AttributeError: 'X' object has no attribute '_a'
>>> x.a = 'foo'
>>> x.a
'foo'
```

Notice that in each case, the way that client code accesses the attribute or property is exactly the same. There's no need to "future-proof" your class against the possibility that at some point you might want to do something more complex than simple attribute access, so no reason to write properties, getters or setters *unless you actually need them right now*.

For more on the differences between idiomatic Python and some other languages when it comes to properties, getters and setters, see:

- [Why don't you want getters and setters?](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.cl/2015/01/why-dont-you-want-getters-and-setters.html)
- [Python is not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html) (especially the "Getters and setters are evil" section)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "A property should only be used if you need to do some work when accessing an attribute:" ?

Comment: @guy it seems self-explanatory to me in the context of the answer as a whole ... what do you find confusing about it, may I ask?

Comment: I'm struggling to determine when to use / not use the @property decorator. I thought it automatically made an attribute read-only but it seems like it is not the case. I also thought that if you have an attribute that is calculated from other attributes then you want this decorator but I don't know why.....

Comment: @guy Without a setter, a property does look like a read-only attribute from the outside, but that's not what it's *for*, and in fact the idea of deliberately making an attribute read-only goes against Python's "consenting adults" philosophy in any case. Properties are, as you say, meant for attributes that require some computation to happen while accessing them. A complete tutorial on their purpose and use is out of scope for this answer; apart from the links I already gave, maybe [this article](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/01/20/python-201-properties/) will be useful to you.