# Creating file access team roaster in python

Tags: python, file-access

I am having trouble grasping how to create a save file for this team roster. The issue I run into is when I try to create what to save in the txt file. Im not sure why i cant get self.player etc to be written in the code. Based on how the players information is written how should I write the txt file to be saved and loaded?

```
class teamClass:

    Player = ""
    phone_number = ""
    jersey = ""

    def __init__(self, Player, phone_number, jersey):
        self.Player = Player

        self.phone_number = phone_number

        self.jersey = jersey

    def setPlayer(self, Player):
        self.Player = Player

    def setphone_number(self, phone_number):
        self.phone_number = phone_number

    def setjersey(self, jersey):
        self.jersey = jersey

    def setNewPlayer(self, Player):
        self.setPlayer(Player)

    # accessor methods

    def getPlayer(self):
        return self.Player

    def getphone_number(self):
        return self.phone_number

    def getjersey(self):
        return self.jersey

    def displayData(self):
        print("")

        print("Player Info: ")

        print("------------------------")

        print("Player:", self.Player)

        print("Phone number:", self.phone_number)

        print("Jersey:", self.jersey)
```

Comment: Fix your indentation, it's out of whack.

Comment: yeah sorry it didnt copy over correctly

Comment: You might want to share the code you've written for your save process.  This is just a class with nothing related to saving to a file.

Answer (score 0):

First, there are quite a few problems with your code:

- Do not create useless class-attributes and override them using instance-attributes. Use a constructor like `__init__(self, name=None, phone=None, jersay=None)` instead.
- [Do not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/python-property-versus-getters-and-setters) use getters and setters like you would in Java. Python assumes that all attributes can be accessed without side-effects; if you truly need a getter/setter for an attribute, use a `@property`.
- You do not want a `displayData`-method. Instead, [define](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) a `__str__()`-method and just call `print()` on the instance.

Concerning your question: You can use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), toml or just [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to save your object. Here is a [toml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/toml/0.9.2) library ready for use.

An example using json:

```
import collections
import json
Player = collections.namedtuple('Player', ('name', 'phone_number', 'jersay'))

# Create a new player instance
p = Player('John Doe', '555-ACME', None)

# Save the player-data to a json-file
with open('thefile.txt', 'wt') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(p))

# Load it back
with open('thefile.txt', 'rt') as f:
    p2 = Player(*json.loads(f.read()))

# Look, ma! They are the same
assert p == p2
```