# Using "private" variable + method v.s. "public" instance variable

Tags: python, design-patterns

I often see this pattern:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self._bar = bar

    def bar(self):
        return _bar
```

Why would that be preferable to this?

```
 class Foo:
     def __init__(self, bar)
         self.bar = bar
```

Comment: This is for Java, but I think the spirit of it still answers your question [Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters). In python specifically, [see `@property`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/python-property-versus-getters-and-setters)

Comment: because you cannot change `bar` reference without using `self._bar` in the first case. In the second case, anything is possible, the variable is less "protected".

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think this answers the question most directly. The reason to use a method is that it protects the reference from being altered (assuming the user knows not to touch `_variables`) while making the value easily accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first code, this would be preferable sometimes for some reasons. For one, in Python `_name` is just a  naming convention that indicates to the developer that `_name` should not be accessed from outside the place where its define, be it a class, a module or whatever. This naming convention also helps to avoid name collisions, especially if the attribute is critical in terms of functionality.

Let's demonstrate with real examples. You'll find many examples of these in the `os.py` module, for instance:

```
# Helper for popen() -- a proxy for a file whose close waits for the process
class _wrap_close:
    def __init__(self, stream, proc):
        self._stream = stream
        self._proc = proc
              ...
```

`_wrap_close` is a wrapper class that's returned when you call `os.popen` .`_proc`. This doesn't just indicate that you shouldn't access this directly in your code, but also might be an indicator that this attribute is critical to the functionality of the class, if you look inside, `os.popen` you will probably see why:

```
# Supply os.popen()
def popen(cmd, mode="r", buffering=-1):
    # many code omitted here...
    if mode == "r":
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                                shell=True,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                bufsize=buffering)
        return _wrap_close(io.TextIOWrapper(proc.stdout), proc)
  # many code omitted here... (see os.py)
```

`_wrap_close` is a wrapper class around the object returned by `Popen` and in fact `_wrap_close` delegates many operations and accesses to `self._proc`. `_wrap_close` itself uses `_name` naming convention.

In some cases:

```
def bar(self):
    return self._bar
```

typically there would be some processing and logic prior to returning `self._bar`. Also properties and descriptors can be used as well. Different developers use different features for different reasons.

Comment: @Bill Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: "typically there would be some processing and logic prior to returning self._bar"

@direprobs my question is specifically about cases where there is no processing logic prior to returning. Why create the method at all in those cases?

Comment: @Bill Can you provide us with a real example where you encountered this?

Comment: here's an example: class Lemma from the NLTK WordNet package http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.html#Lemma @direprobs

Comment: @Bill It does seem the developers wanted to immune themselves from future changes before the introduction of properties That's if the need arises to shift from simple attributes to do some processing in the future instead of just returning a plain attribute, changing to functions would be difficult, because this would break a lot of codes. What's the likelihood of my speculation being right? The code is written in 2.X and that's only what I know. Anyway, don't agitate yourself! Just know that `_name` is a naming convention that denotes internal attributes of objects.

Answer (score 0):

It de-couples the external representation of `bar` from its internal representation.

Comment: This only explains half of the question though - is there any reason to use a method when properties exist?

Comment: @Rawing the answer to that is, emphatically no!

Comment: So the question is asking about properties w/o using the word -- quite clever!