# Is it worth using Python's @property decorator if you don't mind using a method to access a property?

Tags: python, methods, properties, decorator, getter-setter

Update:
Thanks for the responses. I think it finally helped make things click in my head now.

Python prescribes this workflow:

1. start by just using properties and avoid over-engineering with boilerplate getter/setter
2. when more logic is necessary, switch over to getter/setter using the `@property` decorator to maintain a consistent API to reduce refactoring

As oppose to these workflows:

1. start out using getter/setter to avoid refactoring later.

   - this adds unnecessary boilerplate code that might never be needed

or

1. start out using properties
2. switch to non-`@property` getter/setter when more logic is necessary
3. refactor all dependent code to use getter/setter instead of properties

Thanks again for helping me understand these timeline of events and the awesome usefulness of `@property`.

If either of you want to add an answer, I'll accept it to close this out.
Thanks again

Original:

I've been reading up on Python's `@property` decorator.

I understand that it is useful to allow library users to get properties like `class.property` while allowing library maintainers to refactor the getter logic behind the property-like interface much like a getter method.

What I don't understand is, why go through the hassle of using decorators to achieve an interface  that resembles a property, like `class.property`.  What is wrong with have a normal method like interface, like `class.property()`?

Is there something I'm missing?  I don't understand why the extra parenthesis in the method call is problematic enough to warrant using a decorator?

Maybe the following code can help explain what I'm trying to get at better?:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def value(self):
        return self._value

print(Class('calling method').value())

class Class:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

print(Class('accessing property').value)
```

Is it because it makes setters prettier?
So instead of:
`klass.set_value('some value')`
you can have?:
`klass.value = 'some value'`

Like this example code?:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def value(self):
        return self._value

    def set_value(self, value):
        self._value = value

klass = Class('calling method')
klass.set_value('calling method2')
print(klass.value())

class Class:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = value

klass = Class('accessing property')
klass.value = 'accessing property2'
print(klass.value)
```

Are the reasons to use the `@property` decorator purely to make the class interface more aesthetically pleasing?

I do think the interface ends up looking nicer, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something more.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: No. In both of these cases, you should use *neither a `property` nor getter/setter methods*. Because your *getter/setters don't do anything*. This should just be `self.value = value` in `__init__` with no `property` and access it `klass.value`

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/using-property-versus-getters-and-setters

Comment: The *whole point* of `property` is to provide *encapsulation without boilerplate getters and setters*. So you have your class, with your value, and when you create it you only need simple access and modification. Now, if *at some point* you want to control the access of `self.value`, you can *then* use a property which has some non-trivial getter or setter, *without breaking the rest of your class implementation*.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga and Thierry Lathuille.  I've updated the question based on your comments.  Please feel free to write an answer to close this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just post an answer to close out this thread, since the commenters seem like they are busy:

Python prescribes this workflow:

1. start by just using properties and avoid over-engineering with boilerplate getter/setter
2. when more logic is necessary, switch over to getter/setter using the `@property` decorator to maintain a consistent API to reduce refactoring

As oppose to these workflows:

1. start out using getter/setter to avoid refactoring later.

   - this adds unnecessary boilerplate code that might never be needed

or

1. start out using properties
2. switch to non-@property getter/setter when more logic is necessary
3. refactor all dependent code to use getter/setter instead of properties

I hope this helps others better understand the reason Python prescribes the use of `@property`.