# when to use getter and setter with property?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, properties

When should you use a property with getters/setters?  It is not pythonic or wrong to not use a property with getters and setters?  Should or shouldn't I write it with a property?

Examples:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, age):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.age = age

    def say_hi(self):
        print(f"""Hi i'm {self.firstname} {self.lastname} and i'm {self.age}""")

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, newage):
        if not isinstance(newage, int):
            raise TypeError("Expect an Integer")
        self._age = newage
```

versus

```
class Person2:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, age):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.age = age

    def say_hi(self):
        print(f"""Hi i'm {self.firstname} {self.lastname} and i'm {self.age}""")

    def get_age(self):
        return self.age

    def set_age(self, newage):
        if not isinstance(newage, int):
            raise TypeError("Expect an Integer")
        self.age = newage
```

Comment: Python properties *exist* so that you don't have to do the clunky Java thing with `get_age` and `set_age`. Don't write Java in Python. In Java, we have to protect all fields with getters/setters because there's no better way. In Python, a field access and a property access look exactly the same, so we get uniform access principle *and* nice syntax for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using @property versus getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/using-property-versus-getters-and-setters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should generally prefer to use "protected" variables (such as those starting with `_`) with properties (not separate functions that users need to call, that's just clunky), as it confers some advantages. This encapsulation is very handy as it:

- lets you control the internal data completely, such as preventing people entering ages like `-42` (which they *will* do if they can); and
- lets you change the underlying *implementation* in any manner you want, without affecting clients.

For example on that last point, you may want to maintain a separate structure of all names and simply store references to those names in your `Person` class. This can allow you to store many *more* names, as the surname "Von Grimmelshausen" would be stored *once* (in the separate structure) and as much smaller indexes in all the `Person` objects that use it.

You can then totally change the naive `getter` from:

```py
@property
def surname(self):
    return self._surname
```

to:

```py
@property
def surname(self):
    return self._surname_db[self._surname_index]
```

without *any* changes to clients.

Comment: Misses the point, I think. The point of properties is that you can change naive fields (`self.surname`) into properties with no changes to the client code. Using properties from the beginning, even when unnecessary, is just contrary to this simplicity and defeats the point of them having uniform access to fields.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: my advice is that you should always use getters and setters (of some variety, preferably implicit properties in Python) rather than allowing unfettered access to internal state, unless there is a good reason to allow a property to become any value (and there are very few use cases for allowing that). That doesn't just mean variables out of range, it also means variables of whole different types. Think, for example, if one of your properties is a list and you allow a user to do object.should_be_a_list = sys.exit. Hilarity will almost certainly ensue :-)

Comment: That's the opposite of duck typing; if you have an attribute that's normally a list, anything that follows the list protocol should be OK

Comment: It's not like python even has protected or private attributes; there's a naming convention and that's about it

Answer (score 3):

The pythonic way would be not to use setters and getters at all; just have an attribute:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, age):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.age = age

    def say_hi(self):
        print(f"Hi i'm {self.firstname} {self.lastname} and i'm {self.age}")
```

If you want to check types, use type annotations and a checker like `mypy`:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, age):
        self.firstname: str = firstname
        self.lastname: str = lastname
        self.age: int = age

    def say_hi(self):
        print(f"Hi i'm {self.firstname} {self.lastname} and i'm {self.age}")
```

If it later turns out that you do need to do something more complex, you can always turn it into a property later with no change of interface.

Comment: And when some user (or, more likely, tester) does `person.age = -42`, how will you handle that? :-)

Comment: Is that from input or from code? From input, you'd do validation at input, along with parsing. From code, the programmer is assumed to be part of the crew; we're all adults.

Comment: sabik, my opinion is that each layer is responsible for checking their *own* constraints. That's why you have pre-condition checks in functions, RAII, or relationships enforced in databases (rather than in user code). If it's in the layer that relies on it, you implement it once. Otherwise, you implement it in every piece of code that uses the layer. And "we're all adults" belies the fact that some of those adults actively look for potential holes like that to bypass security :-) Unlikely for a person class but certainly so in the more general sense.

Answer (score 0):

"Pythonic" is a holy struggle.

I personally prefer the Class under full control.

In your case:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, age):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.age = age

    def say_hi(self):
        print(f"Hi i'm {self.firstname} {self.lastname} and i'm {self.age}")

    def test_str(self, cosi):
        return self.test(cosi, str)

    @staticmethod
    def test(cosi, neco):
        assert isinstance(cosi, neco), f"Bad value! {cosi} is not instance" \
                                       f" from {neco.__name__}"
        return cosi

    @staticmethod
    def test_positiv_int(num):
        assert 0 < int(num), f"Expect an positiv integer"  # negative value protect
        return int(num)  # if int is like string this returned int

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        # important!!!:
        whitedict = dict(firstname=self.test_str,
                         lastname=self.test_str,
                         age=self.test_positiv_int
                         )
        # Call fn from whitedict with parameter
        self.__dict__[key] = whitedict[key](value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second version of your code (referring to class2) utilizes two instance methods i.e `get_age` and
`set_age` which are not serving much of a purpose because you can retrieve the age attribute of an instance without calling the `get_age` method, also you can set the age attribute to literally anything without invoking your `set_age` method. Also if you want user to retrieve or set the age attribute using your given instance methods, the user who was using your class previously will have to make changes in their code which is something we do not want.

---

Now, the first version of your code (referring to class1) is very helpful because you can pose restrictions on the age attribute by using property decorators. You can make the age attribute read only or both read and write and you can just retrieve or set the age attribute of an instance normally without having to call any methods.

Also, as you explicitly need to call the `set_age` method on an instance in second version of your code, for this
piece of logic :

```
if not isinstance(newage, int):
    raise TypeError("Expect an Integer")
self._age = newage
```

to execute so the user cannot put any arbitrary value into the age attribute, on the other hand it happens implicitly whenever you try to set the age attribute when you use properties.