# Issue with object programming and files

Tags: python, csv, file, object, typeerror

I was trying to write a code and check it with pytest. I thought I did everything ok, but I got a problem. After writing this, I want to check it with method of class Person. When I tried to use method id the function ends and I got the output:

```
 TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

My code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, id, name, sex, birth_date):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.sex = sex
        self.birth_date = birth_date

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} born {self.birth_date} with {self.sex} has {self.id}'

    def name(self):
        return self.name

    def sex(self):
        return self.sex

    def id(self):
        return self.id

    def date_of_birth(self):
        return self.birth_date

def read_from_file(file_handle):
        people = []
        reader = csv.DictReader(file_handle)
        for row in reader:
            id = row['id']
            name = row['name']
            sex = row['sex']
            birth_date = row['birth_date']
            person = Person(id, name, sex, birth_date)
            print(person.id())[Error in this line]
            people.append(person)
        return people

def test_files():
    with open('people.txt', 'r') as people_txt:
        people = read_from_file(people_txt)
```

Example of line of people.txt:

```
id,name,sex,birth_date

1,Doralyn Dovermann,Female,27/10/2005
2,Rickert Petschel,Male,10/7/2018
3,Whitney Girardoni,Female,7/3/1932
```

Comment: Which line does the error message point to?

Comment: Please always include the complete Traceback. Format it as code.

Comment: Line number is missing, also just a tip: you have id as a function and then you are defining the attribute variable within your constructor as `self.id`, might be better to rename either one to keep the naming convention clean.

Comment: It points the print(person.id()). I don't know why it works like that, but I think that person is not an object.

Comment: It works like that because you are instantiating `Person()` class and carries all the method with it to the defined `person`. Possibly look into Inheritance and OOP topics.

Comment: So this is why I got output :  TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. I know what you mean, but I don't think it causes a problem.

Comment: Again, like everyone else mentioned, include the full traceback with the line number.

Comment: Comment out these methods `def name(self): ..., def sex(self): ..., def id(self): ..., def date_of_birth(self): ...` then try it.

Comment: May be of interest: [Using @property versus getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/using-property-versus-getters-and-setters)

Comment: You're using the same  names for your methods that you use for the attributes they're supposed to return. That can't work. An attribute lookup like `person.id` can only find either the attribute *or* the method, not both (instance attributes take precedence). It's not obvious why you're written the methods at all (getter methods are not generally used in Python).

Answer (score 2):

That error occurs when you try to call a string as if it were a function. In your code you call `person.id()`, but `person.id` is not a function. If you want to print the contents of the string attribute, just do `print(person.id)`.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing but I want to be sure about what I do. Why method person.id() doesn't works. I haven't found errors like that when I tried to call the method of class.

Comment: @New_stud read his answer again; expecially the "but person.id is not a function"-part

Comment: So as I understand, everything is because of names of functions? I' am so sorry, I didn't expect that the problem is not very deep. I was focused on looking for small mistake or smth like that.

Comment: @New_stud It is a small mistake, a `()` where there shouldn't have been. Adding `()` to the end of a name is telling python to call/execute that name. Basic objects like strings can not be executed.