# Which is the best way to declare an attribute of a class that is set to a method call?

Tags: python, oop

I have two approaches to initialize an object:

```py
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = None
        self.get_foo()
    
    def get_foo(self):
        # do complex stuff
        self.foo = something

class Class2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = self.get_foo()
    
    def get_foo(self):
        # do complex stuff
        return something
```

Which one is the best approach according to Software Engineering and/or OOP best practices? Or maybe neither?

Comment: Is `get_a()`  always return the value of attribute `a`? Is/should be user able to set the attribute `a`?

Comment: I prefer `Class2`. There is no reason to initialize it to None if you're about to initialize it on the next line.

Comment: It looks like `self.a` should just be a `property` or `cached_property`.

Comment: @buran that should represent a complex operation, I'm gonna edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: I understand that it's probably [complex] calculation. I mean is it possible value of `a` change in a different way except from calculations in `get_a`.  Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/2627002/4046632 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/6618002/4046632

Comment: Initializing `self.foo` to `None` only to immediately change its value is kind of pointless. Initializing `self.foo = None` until `self.get_foo` is called *later* makes more sense. That's a fairly common design, where a property `foo` waits until it is accessed to compute a value and save it to an underlying attribute `_foo` that can be retrieved on subsequent calls.